# How do I set up a Stripe payment form in React?

Tags: stripe-payments, react-stripe

I'm building a web app in React, and want to be able to accept Stripe payments.  I've followed the documentation on their site, but something is clearly missing because it's throwing an error.  During the process I haven't at any point specified how much the user should be paying, or anything like that, so I imagine that's the issue, but I can't find anything in the docs which shows me how to set that up (I found a bit about PaymentIntents, which I think is related, but I've no idea where to use that).

So, the process is that the user signs up, I send their details to the backend, and (if everything is ok) the backend returns `stripeID` (cus_****) and `paymentIntentID` (pi_*****).  We only have one product, which is a monthly subscription at a set price, so the `paymentIntentID` will indicate that the payment is for that product.

Once I have that information, I want to show them a Stripe payment page which allows them to pay for the subscription.  If that's successful, I want to redirect them to a dashboard; if there's an error, I want to show it and let them retry the payment.

I've installed the `react-stripe-js` package.

In App.js I have (currently `myPublishableKey` (pk_test_***) and `myClientSecret` (sk_test_***) are hardcoded, but obviously I'll change that):

```
<Elements stripe={loadStripe(myPublishableKey)} options={{ clientSecret: myClientSecret }}>
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LayoutMain />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="signup" element={<SignUp/>}
          />
          <Route
            path="payment" element={<Payment />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Elements>
```

In the `SignUp` component, there's basically a form asking for name etc; in the `onSubmit` method of the form, the form details are sent to the backend; if the submission is successful (basically as long as they don't already have an account), then the returned data is saved to the context (this includes `stripeID` and `paymentIntentID`) and the user is sent to the `Payment` page:

```
    const onSubmit = () => {
      try {
        const res = await postData('user/create_user', {...formState});
        appDispatch({ type: 'onGetUser', user: { ...res } });
        // Navigate to stripe payment page
        navigate('/payment');
      } catch {
        setSubmissionError(true);
      }
    }
```

Then I created a `Payment` Component, following the Stripe docs:

```
const Payment = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }

    const result = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      elements,
      confirmParams: { return_url: ON_SUCCESS_URL },
    });

    if (result.error) {
      console.log(result.error.message);
    } else {
      console.log('ok');
    }
  };

  return (
    <MainContainer>
      <InnerContainer>
        <Centred>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <PaymentElement />
            <Button>Submit</Button>
          </form>
        </Centred>
      </InnerContainer>
    </MainContainer>
  );
};

export default Payment;
```

When I view the Payment component, the console shows the error `"v3:1 Uncaught IntegrationError: In order to create a payment element, you must pass a valid PaymentIntent or SetupIntent client secret when creating the Elements group"`.

I'm just not sure how to do that!  I'm setting the clientSecret in App.js - at that point I don't have the paymentIntentID.  Do I need to pass the paymentIntentID into something in the Payment component?  If so, what?

Comment: Where do you invoke your `<Payment />` component? Can you update your question to include contents of `<MyApp />`? What is the value of `myClientSecret`?

Comment: Thanks.  I've added those details.  `myClientSecret` is: sk_test_******

Comment: Your `myClientSecret` variable is in the wrong format. It needs to be a valid [`client_secret`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret) returned from a either Payment or Setup Intent. You'll need to create one of those objects first before you can initialise the Payment Element.

Comment: Thanks.  So, I need to take the paymentIntentID and retrieve the PaymentIntent, is that right?  And then where do I use that?  It can't be in App.js as I don't have the intent ID at that point.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the back end creates the Payment Intent and returns the paymentIntentID, which is what I'm getting back.  So I tried to do stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(paymentIntentID) to get the PaymentIntent, but I get the error `Invalid value for stripe.retrievePaymentIntent intent secret: value should be a client secret of the form ${id}_secret_${secret}`

Comment: When you create your Payment Intent, the `client_secret` will be returned in the response from the Stripe API. You need to return that value from your backend (that creates the Payment Intent) to your React application. You likely need to co-locate the `<Elements />` component somewhere in your application that can make the request to create the Payment Intent. There's a complete React example of this flow [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?client=react&lang=node).

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to figure it out from that flow you linked to.  Basically I was using the wrong ID, as you said.